# Fabric Composer o vs -->

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I can't find any docs on this, so what is the difference between `o` and `-->` in [Fabric Composer](https://fabric-composer.github.io/index.html), and under what circumstances should they be used?

Consider this...

```
asset Document identified by docId {
    o String docId
    o Articles[] articles
}
```

vs this...

```
asset Document identified by docId {
    o String docId
    --> Articles[] articles
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a document about CTO language. This document mentions about has-a relationship (o) and reference (-->).

Fabric Composer Modeling Language
https://fabric-composer.github.io/reference/cto_language.html

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: This is the working link: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/reference/cto_language.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm just learning about Hyperledger, but I saw a reference in this video https://youtu.be/6nGIptzBZis?t=17m (minute 17 and beyond).

> 'o' indicates has-a relationship
>
> '-->' indicates pass by reference

Hope that helps =)

Comment: I would not refer to `-->` as "pass by reference" -- it is declaring something more like a foreign key relationship in DB terms, or just a relationship in entity-relationship terms. Essentially it is a typed pointer to an instance.

Comment: @DanSelman just quoting the text on the slide in the link provided :)